# Laravel DataTables move to domain class

Tags: laravel, datatables, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I've managed to correctly set up a Laravel DataTable with the following code in a controller method.

```php
// Retrieve (potentially filtered) data
$users = User::with("role", "language", "country")->select([
    "support_code", "first_name", "last_name", "subscription_expires", 
    "email_address", "user_name", "location",
    "role_id", "language_id", "country_id"
]);

// Return data as JSON
return Datatables::of($users)->make(true);
```

However, I now wish to move this code out of the controller and into a domain object/separate class. The problem is that this doesn't work as the DataTables JS sends a long query string via its Ajax method, and this isn't being passed along to the domain class.

I have two questions. First, how do I send this query string to the domain class? Second, how do I offer it up to the `Datatables::of($users) -> make(true)` method?

Answer (score 0):

Lol. My fault. I forgot to include `use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;`

Because it was an Ajax request, I didn't get the namespace error message.